# Django kills older requests

Tags: django, ajax, iis, request, celery

I am running a Django website over IIS. When a user saves an object it can take some time, so rather than have them wait for it to finish an AJAX request is sent to the server with the submission information and the page is immediately redirected. However, if the server gets many more requests that old saving request is killed rather inelegantly. The log files show that it ends mid execution with no error messages or other indication that it failed.

How do I keep older requests alive in Django?

P.S. I have already investigated starting a new multithreading Process but encountered issues around Django models, and I am looking for something more simple than Celery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Django wasn't killing the requests, IIS was. There is a timeout setting for FastCGI, the medium between Django and IIS, that was set to 30 seconds. So when my saving request hit that time limit it just ended with no warning.

You can change this by clicking on the server name in IIS, then clicking the "FastCGI Settings" icon, then clicking the FastCGI application being used. Under "Process Model", change "Activity Timeout" and "Request Timeout" to a higher limit, I used 300 for 5 minutes to be safe.